# Como ficaria a conversão deste algoritimo de C para Python

Tags: c, python

```
unsigned char CheckSum(unsigned char *uBuff, unsigned char uBuffLen){
  unsigned char i, uSum=0;
  for(i=0; i < uBuffLen; i++){
    uSum = uSum + uBuff[i];
  }
  uSum = (~uSum) + 1;
  return uSum;
}
```

Comment: Você sabe Python? Se sim, o que tentou? Qual foi a dificuldade?

Comment: Conheço sim. O que não consegui fazer foi entender o código simples em C, mais especificamente na parte "uSum = (~uSum) + 1" que acredito ser uma conversão para complemento de dois.

Answer (score 3):

O algoritmo é direto em Python, sem nenhuma alteração - no entanto, a composição do valor final, que tem que ser binário, tem que ter alguns cuidados. Pra começar, claro que o buffer tem que ser um objeto do tipo "bytes" ou algum outro que itere um byte de cada vez (bytearray, memoryview, array.array, etc...). Como em Python esses objetos já tem o comprimento conhecido, não é necessário o segundo parâmetro.

O "for" poderia ser feito com 3 linhas:

```
result = 0
for element in buffer:
    result += element
```

Mas - aí você nota que se é só para somar todos os elementos de um iterável, a função nativa [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) de Python já faz isso - ou seja, as 3 linhas acima são equivalentes a:

```
result = sum(buffer)
```

Daí entra a parte em que se tem que saber o que está acontecendo com os números- independente da linguagem. Na sua função em C, o acumulador "uSum" é um *unsigned Char*, o que significa que é uma variável que só comporta números de 0 a 255 (8 bits) - e quando a soma extrapola isso, os bits superiores são simplesmente descartados na própria arquitetura da máquina (na CPU).

Os números inteiros em Python, por padrão, tem comprimento indeterminado - então a função `sum` retorna a soma total dos bytes de um buffer. Para descartar os bits nas posições maiores que 8, e ficar só com o valor entre 0 e 255, temos duas opções: colocar esse número numa estrutura de dados que só aceite números de 8 bit, descartando o restante - como acontece em C, ou, usa o operador binário "e" bit-a-bit (`&` tanto em Python quanto em C) , com um número que tenha só os 8 bits que interessam em 1 - (isso garante que todos os outros vão pra 0). Ou ainda o operador de módulo (`%`)  - resto de divisão - já que queremos somente os bits mais baixos.

A primeira opção na verdade é um pouco mais complicada - por que ao contrário de C, em que você deve saber o que está fazendo e se trunca ou perde bits dos seus dados é um problema seu. (pode haver *warnings* em tempo de compilação, mas o código da sua função mesmo é válido), o Python por via de regra vai dar um erro se você tentar colocar um número maior que 255 num único byte. A segunda opção no entanto é bem simples, e podemos inclusive representar a máscara direto em binário mesmo:

```
result = sum(buffer) & 0b11111111
```

O operador de complemento de 2 que tanto preocupou você, é exatamente o mesmo em Python - o `~` unário. Só que, como anteriormente, o número operado  - ou seja, até aqui a função inteira poderia ser escrita como:

```
def checksum(buffer):
    result = ~(sum(buffer) & 0b11111111) + 1
    return result
```

Agora - tem uma última coisa - que  é justamente porque o complemento de 2 é feito numa variável de 1 byte sem sinal em C: o resultado é sempre positivo em C. Em Python, novamente, com seus números sem limitação, o resultado é negativo. Então para termos esse número positivo de volta, a melhor forma pode ser colocar esse número dentro de um objeto bytes criado pelo módulo `struct` do Python - e então ler esse byte. Isso por que o método  `struct.pack`  permite definir exatamente como interpretar o número dado como bytes na memória - e então dizemos que queremos importar nosso número menor que 8 bits com sinal - (usando o código "b" [como na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)) - e ler esse byte depois:

```
import struct

def checksum(buffer):
    result = sum(buffer) & 0b11111111
    result = ~result + 1
    result = struct.pack("b", result)[0]
    return result
```